# Pass data from one dialog to another in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the data from second dialog to root dialog. For that, I lifted the state up inside the parent component and passing down the state value as props to the dialog. However, the state is not updating right away. I should click on the agree button twice inside the Second dialog to see the updated state.

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/alertdialog-material-demo-forked-jyekq?file=/demo.js). Could anyone please help?

**Excerpt from my code**

```
export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [openSecondDialog, setOpenSecondDialog] = React.useState(false);
  const [userConfirmed, setUserConfirmed] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleAgreeOnDialog1 = () => {
    handleClickOpenSecondDialog();
    console.log("userConfirmed", userConfirmed);
  };

  const handleAgreeOnSecondDialog = () => {
    setUserConfirmed(true);
    handleCloseSecondDialog();
  };
  const handleDisagreeOnSecondDialog = () => {
    setUserConfirmed(false);
    handleCloseSecondDialog();
  };

  const handleClickOpenSecondDialog = () => {
    setOpenSecondDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseSecondDialog = () => {
    setOpenSecondDialog(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        fullWidth={true}
        maxWidth="md"
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">Dialog 1</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>Dialog 1 content</DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleAgreeOnDialog1} autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
        <SecondDialog
          openSecondDialog={openSecondDialog}
          handleClickOpenSecondDialog={handleClickOpenSecondDialog}
          handleCloseSecondDialog={handleCloseSecondDialog}
          handleAgreeOnSecondDialog={handleAgreeOnSecondDialog}
          handleDisagreeOnSecondDialog={handleDisagreeOnSecondDialog}
        />
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is what you find?

```js
function App() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [openSecondDialog, setOpenSecondDialog] = React.useState(false);
  const [userConfirmed, setUserConfirmed] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleAgreeOnDialog1 = () => {
    handleClickOpenSecondDialog();
    console.log("userConfirmed", userConfirmed);
  };

  const handleAgreeOnSecondDialog = () => {
    setUserConfirmed(true);
    handleCloseSecondDialog();
  };
  const handleDisagreeOnSecondDialog = () => {
    setUserConfirmed(false);
    handleCloseSecondDialog();
  };

  const handleClickOpenSecondDialog = () => {
    setOpenSecondDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseSecondDialog = () => {
    setOpenSecondDialog(false);
  };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={handleClickOpen}>
          Open alert dialog
        </button>
        {open && <div>
          <p>Dialog 1 content</p>
          <div>
            <button onClick={handleClose}>Disagree</button>
            <button onClick={handleAgreeOnDialog1}>
              Agree
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>}
        {openSecondDialog && <div>
          <p>Dialog 2 content</p>
          <div>
            <button onClick={handleDisagreeOnSecondDialog}>Disagree</button>
            <button onClick={handleAgreeOnSecondDialog}>
              Agree
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>}
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```